# Back navigation duplicates the previous page

Tags: nativescript, mapbox-android, angular-nativescript

I upgraded to the newest NativeScript version (8.4) with Angular 13. `tns doctor` says everything is OK.

I have an outlet.
The root route is a page with a mapbox map.
When I navigate forward from the root route in the same outlet, everything happens as expected, I get the new page perfectly.

But when I navigate back I can see the previous Page for one second, then a blank screen, then the same page re-starts.

I can see in the console `ngOninit()` runs again when it shouldn't do anything just show the previous page again.

I figured out the map gets duplicated and it causes crashes.

```
    if (this._routerExtensions.canGoBack) {
      this._routerExtensions.back({ relativeTo: this.route });
    }
```

```
  {
    path: 'map',
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,

    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../../libs/xplat/nativescript/features/src/lib/pages/map').then(m => m.MapModule),
    outlet: 'map',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]

  },
  {
    path: 'nearby/:id',
    //component: NSEmptyOutletComponent, // navigating back doesn't work when this is active
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../../../libs/xplat/nativescript/features/src/lib/pages/nearby').then(m => m.NearbyModule),
    outlet: 'map',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]

  },
```

Everything worked perfectly with 8.2, I had to upgrade because 8.2 couldn't handle the downloaded files after Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating to latest angular (and `@nativescript/angular`) as a lot of fixes regarding navigation were done since angular 13.

Comment: thank you, as I know NS is not compatible with that and that's the problem actually